# django, order matters when applying multiple query filters?

Tags: django, filter

Does `order` of `filter` matter when you query in django?

MyModel.objects.filter(exp1).filter(exp2)

vs

MyModel.objects.filter(exp2).filter(exp1)

Are they same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just doing two simple `filter` operations, then you're correct that order doesn't matter, but be careful.  There are examples of when the order of your queryset methods do matter:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Rather than thinking of `filter` as being fundamentally commutative, you're probably safer thinking of each queryset methods as being generally iterative upon the whatever preceded them.  Multiple filters are not always simple SQL AND's.  Take [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) for example (although it's still commutative in this case).

Answer (score 0):

filter(exp1).filter(exp2) filters according to exp1 and then subfilter exp2 (restricting furthermore the result queryset, with results that are ALSO in exp2)

so actually your answer is yes, they are the same, since this acts like an ordinary AND query